# Chrome window display issue

Tags: unity, google-chrome

I m running Ubuntu 14.04 with ATI Raedon 6670 video card. Using Unity

there is this irritating issue, u can see here: http://screencloud.net/v/cRMA

It seems unlike other application, chrome fails to calculate available screen area, so it has a gap between unity bar and the left edge of the window.

Is there any fix? or do i have to wait for chrome to get updated?

thanks!

Update: I didn't notice this earlier, but now i notice, if i have chrome on single window with one or more tabs in it, the visual glitch is not in there. But as soon as i open a page in new window, this appears. This might be a bug related to chrome rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here.
I have dissabled hardware acceleration in chrome system settings and it worked.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Could you elaborate a bit on this? (which menu / command you used so that a user of less reputation then OP can follow your instructions as well???)  **;-)**